# How to get grade calculation option values using Valence APIs?

Tags: desire2learn, valence

Is there some way to get the grade calculation option values for course sections using the Valence APIs? I looked through the [Grades](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html) documentation, but couldn't find anything. What I'm trying to get are the following.

- Grading System: Weighted, Points, or Formula
- Final Grade Released: Calculated Final Grade or Adjusted Final Grade
- Ungraded Items: Drop ungraded items or Treat ungraded items as 0
- Auto Update: Automatically keep final grades updated

I've also tried looking at [Configuration Variables](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/config.html), but that doesn't seem relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can meet some of these goals with [GradeCategories via the API](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html#grade-categories), but I believe that some of them are not currently accessible through the API.

Comment: Yeah, there doesn't appear to be an API that deals with the various gradebook settings such as Calculation Options. I've decided to just parse the HTML page that they're on.

Comment: While it might be expedient to screen-scrape, this is a really fragile solution, and you shouldn't depend on it long-term; I would recommend that you register your need as an enhancement to the platform via your partner or client account manager.

Answer (score 0):

It does look like you can determine the grading system from the [Grade Categories](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html#grade-categories) section. I see attributes for weight, which would likely be null if the item is not weighted.

Regarding ungraded items, there's this note in the [GradeValue](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html#Grade.GradeValue) section:

> Nullable grade values in the computable grade value structures indicate (when null) a default grade value state before a grade value has actually been assessed.

So your code could get computable GradeValues and ignore any with null or assign 0 to them.

I only see an option to PUT a final adjusted grade value.

Comment: Thanks, it does look like I could derive some of the settings. I've decided it's not worth going down that path will just parse the HTML page with the settings (/d2l/lms/grades/admin/settings/calculation_options.d2l?ou=1234).